# Functions and else ifs

Tags: javascript

I'm still pretty new to JavaScript and need to be pointed in the right direction on a tiny project that is just for practice.

Very sorry if I'm not posting incorrectly, this is my first post on Stack Overflow and any help is appreciated.

```
I've tried accomplishing my goal a few different ways and haven't gotten there. 

attack.addEventListener("click", function(){
hit();
});

function hit(){
    if (bossHealth.textContent > 0 && playerFocus.textContent >=2) {
        playerFocus.textContent -= 2;
        bossHealth.textContent -= 3; 
        console.log("attack");
    }

    else if (bossHealth.textContent >= 0 && playerFocus.textContent < 2){
        alert("Attack costs 2 focus, try regenerating this turn to gain focus and health!");
    }

};

strong.addEventListener("click", function(){
    bigHit();
});

function bigHit(){
    if(bossHealth.textContent > 0 && playerFocus.textContent >= 5){
    playerFocus.textContent -= 6;
    bossHealth.textContent -= 6;
    console.log("strong attack");
    }

    else if (playerFocus <5){
        alert("Strong attack costs 5 focus, if you do not have enough focus try regenerating for a turn");
    }

    else (bossHealth.textContent <= 0){
    bossHealth.textContent = "Dead";
    alert("You've killed the bad guy and saved the world!!!");
    }
};

easy.addEventListener("click", function(){
    reset();
});

function reset(){
    playerHealth.textContent = 10;
    playerFocus.textContent = 10;
    bossHealth.textContent = 10;
};

hard.addEventListener("click", function(){
    hardMode();
});

function hardMode(){
    playerHealth.textContent = 10;
    playerFocus.textContent = 10;
    bossHealth.textContent = 15;
};
```

With function hit I don't get the alert in my else if statement

with function bigHit I also don't get my alert for the else if statement and neither part of the else statement works.

also subtraction works in my functions, but when trying to add another function that uses addition in the same way it adds the number to the end of the string instead of performing math

Comment: Note in your bighit function you are comparing against playerFocus and not its textContent. Also textContent is a string if you need to do addition you need to convert it to a number first (+ acts as addition and string concatenation depending on the type of variable)

Comment: Is textContent an integer, or a string? If it's a string it needs to be playerHealth.textContent.length

Comment: it is because you are using `textContent ` which is a string, you need to convert it to a number first before you can do math on it

Comment: https://codepen.io/cbrand4656/pen/vvKKrP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't depend on what is in the DOM for logic. You should try with local variables then update the DOM based on those variables.

```
var boss = {}
var player = {}

function reset(){
    player.health = 10;
    player.focus = 10;
    boss.health = 10;
    update()
};

function hit(){
  if (boss.health > 0 && player.focus >=2) {
      player.focus -= 2;
      boss.health -= 3; 
      console.log("attack");
  } else if (boss.health > 0 && player.focus < 2){
      alert("Attack costs 2 focus, try regenerating this turn to gain focus and health!");
  }
  update()
}

function update() {
    playerFocus.textContent = player.focus
    playerHealth.textContent = player.health
    bossHealth.textContent = boss.health
}
```

Your issue is caused by `textContent` automatically turning your numbers into strings, by managing the data using your own variables this doesn't affect your code's logic.

Alternatively you could parse the strings as numbers using `new Number(playerFocus.textContent)`, `parseFloat(playerFocus.textContent)`, or `+playerFocus.textContent` but your code will become very hard to read very quickly.

Hope this enough to help you to make more edits to your code.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, this looks like what I've been trying to do and is what I'm referencing as I make changes. Came back for an edit to also say this will keep everything much more clean and concise than I originally had it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `playerFocus` variable is a DOM node? Based on that assumption, your condition is missing a check for its `textContent`:

```
if (bossHealth.textContent > 0 && playerFocus.textContent >= 5){
   // ...
}
else if (playerFocus.textContent <5){
    // ...
```

In JavaScript, `else` blocks cannot have conditions, so if you want to conditionally check whether `bossHealth.textContent <= 0` at the end of your `bigHit` function, you will need to change it to an `else if (bossHealth.textContent <= 0) { ... }` block instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding on to @LoganMurphy's comment and my own. In order to use the value of bossHealth it needs to be an integer. Change your code to look something like this:

```
function hit(){
    if (parseInt(bossHealth.textContent) > 0 && parseInt(playerFocus.textContent) >=2) {
        playerFocus.textContent -= 2;
        bossHealth.textContent -= 3; 
        console.log("attack");
    }

    else if (parseInt(bossHealth.textContent) >= 0 && parseInt(playerFocus.textContent) < 2){
        alert("Attack costs 2 focus, try regenerating this turn to gain focus and health!");
    }

};
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp